# How to define drupal template for individual page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm new to drupal and i've looked several tutorial although i am not quite clear on themeing.
  My main problem is that i've got plain html and i've started to edit it and started to generated to look like drupal dynamically generated page but have got other pages like contact/aboutus and all the static page which are supposed to be only at home page are being displayed at other of my pages how to make drupal understand different pages?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656 . It's very well documented!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "Make Drupal understand different pages"?

You could just create them (Content -> Add content -> Basic page)and they are there.
It you mean theming the pages differently you might want to read https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme
Or if you want to theme specific pages: https://www.drupal.org/node/104316

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use the theme developer module https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer that tells you where you can override different parts of your page.